# can 2 singly-linked list nodes point to each other in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, singly-linked-list

Consider a singly linked list.

First Node : value=v1,address of this node=x,next=y ;

Second Node : value=v2,address of this node=y,next=NULL

```
Linked list pointer *ptr=x;
Linked list pointer *ptr1=y;
ptr1->next=ptr; // This is wrong
```

This will show the error of "heap-use-after-free"
WHY I can't store the address of 2 nodes in each other?

```
ptr->next=NULL //  or any other node address
ptr1->next=ptr; // This is right
```

I can use this but why I can not use the above one?

(I don't need to traverse to the end)

CODE FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDABILITY OF QUESTION

```
 ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode *a,*b,*c;
    a=head;
    if(!a)
        return a;
    a=head->next;
    b=head->next->next;
    head->next=NULL;
    while(b!=NULL)
    {
        c=b->next;
        b->next=a;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    head->next;
    return a;
}
```

This is showing error why?

Comment: There is nothing fundamental about C++ that prevents two objects from pointing to each other. But if your structure is a linked list, it probably assumes that the data is contains is a list and not a loop. And breaking that assumption can cause problems like you are observing.

Comment: What is `Linked` ? The reason for your problem is in its implementation. Nothing in C++ forbids members of objects to point to each other

Comment: Where does it "show the error"? Please edit the question to contain a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Nodes contain an integer value @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @NathanPierson please see again , now i have edit and add the code

Comment: @Shivansh Bhardwaj The function reverseList does not make a sense. For example what this statement head->next; is doing?!

Comment: Recommendation: Use descriptive variable names. This is particularly important when sharing your code with others.

Comment: You've added code, but you haven't added a minimal reproducible example. There isn't enough of `ListNode` to recreate the issue you've described. It seems like @JosephLarson's answer accurately identifies the source of your problems, but your `reverseList` method has others. (What happens to `b` if `head` isn't `nullptr` but `head->next` is?)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the function reverseList is for reversing the entire list and I have use head->next consciously to ask people why this is showing the error of " heap use after free ". Please review it again.

Comment: @NathanPierson you can assume that it has many nodes, no need to worry about a limited number of nodes.

Comment: Until we can compile and run a [mre]. there is very little we can do for you other than guess. Joseph's made a pretty good guess with respect to the initial question about cycles in a linked list, but it's still only a guess. Recommendation: Draw pictures to help yourself visualize the list. Draw a small list and then step-by-step follow your coded instructions exactly to reverse the list.

Answer (score 3):

At what point do you get the error you're talking about? I'm fairly certain it's during destruction, and your destructor frees the entire chain. That is:

```
class MyLinkedList {
public:
     MyLinkedList *next = nullptr;
     int value = 0;

     virtual ~MyLinkedList() {
         if (next != nullptr) {
             delete *next;
         }
};
```

If that's the case, then think about what happens when you delete the the head. You'll end up with these calls:

```
delete x;
which calls delete on it's next (which is y)
which calls delete on it's next (which points back to x)
```

It is exceedingly unlikely the pointer assignment is generating any sort of error. That error happens only after memory has been deleted but you use it again.